# C++ error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'FILE' jpeglib issue?

Tags: c++, libjpeg

I'm following a walk-through that required the jpeglib from http://www.ijg.org/.
After installing the files in jpegsr9a.zip and adding the code that utilizes the files, I get the following errors after compiling:

```
1>  jpeg.cpp
1>c:\libraries\jpeg\jpegsr9a\jpeg\jpeglib.h(974): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'FILE'
1>c:\libraries\jpeg\jpegsr9a\jpeg\jpeglib.h(975): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'FILE'
1>c:\...\jpeg.h(5): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\...\jpeg.h(5): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\...\jpeg.cpp(11): error C2065: 'pBitMap' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\...\jpeg.cpp(16): error C2065: 'pBitMap' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\...\jpeg.cpp(16): error C2227: left of '->sizeX' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>          type is 'unknown-type'
```

There are a lot more, but I think they're all related to the C2061 errors.  Does this look like I've made a mistake when adding the libraries?

The following are the header files in the program:

//heightfield.h

```
#include <Windows.h>
```

//jpeg.h

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <jpeglib.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "jpeg.lib")

tImageJPG *SwiftLoadJpeg(const char *srFileName);

void SwiftTextureJpeg(unsigned int tTexture [], LPSTR strFileName, int ID);
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: include <stdio.h> before including jpeglib.h

Comment: Looks like jpeg.h expects that <stdio.h> be included afore.

Comment: Thanks guys.  That got rid of the C2061 errors, but not the C2143.  Should I update the code above or leave it as is for others to see?  Also, how did you figure out what the problem was?

Comment: @sionv Experience. Compiler didn't seem to understand what `FILE` is, and it's defined in `stdio.h`. Although, the error seems a little confusing.

Comment: @luk32  Thanks!  It seems I should have checked http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/FILE/?kw=FILE and noticed that.

Comment: Once you sort this out, write a scathing email to whomever designed that header file. Frankly it is irresponsible to write headers that require external dependencies fulfilled by *you*, the consumer, before including their types and prototypes unless it is *clearly* defined (and it rarely is; ex: legacy ATL externes modules). If they utilize `FILE` in some parameter list or structure, they should be `#include <stdio.h>` in the header inside the include-guard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see that it does not recognize an identifier, after checking for a typo in the identifier name, 
look for a missing #include.

Since the unrecognized variable was FILE, which is part of the input/output interface in the standard library, the file needed is .

How would you figure this out if you didn't know already?  Look at documentation/help for FILE, or for functions which use FILE.  They should specify which header file is needed.

Your second error, C2143, looks like it is also a missing #include.  It is on line 5.  Look at line 5.  The first * comes after the identifier, tImageJPG.  If the compiler does not recognize tImageJPG, it won't be expecting some thing like "*" after it.  Is this a typedef of yours?  I don't see it in a copy of jpeglib.h that I found online, and you are clearly including  jpeglib.h.  Perhaps there is a header file from your own project which you need to include here.  Or perhaps it has not yet been defined, and the typedef still needs to be written.

Comment: Thank you.  That was the problem with the FILE error.  The solution provided by cup and Andrey (adding an additional include <stdio.h> did the trick)  As for the tImageJPG, I'm guessing it's an error in the tutorial that I'm following (http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl/6_vbo.html).

Comment: I looked briefly at that tutorial and didn't see tImageJPG; if you could direct me to it maybe I can help more with the problem.

Comment: http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/terrain/5_textures.html has a jpeg.cpp file that uses it.  The tutorial doesn't seem to define tImageJpg anywhere though.  I added my own struct definition for it and it got it to compile.

Comment: jpeg.cpp includes jpeg.h.  jpeg.h includes jpeglib.h which defines the structure.  jpeglib.h is in the zip file which is linked to on that page.  If you are using a library and it has a structure in it, I don't recommend redefining the structure yourself; it is just a matter of finding the right include file.  If you define your own and pass it to library functions it might not work -- your definition might differ from theirs.  If it is the same, theirs might change in a future version of their library, causing bugs when you upgrade.